# Working with a list of alists

Tags: list, alists

I have a number of "alists".

```
(defconst assoc-table-1 
  '( ("frantic" . "fN") ("authentic" . "atN") ))

(defconst assoc-table-2
  '( ("graphology" . "Gol") ("phrenology" . "fnol") ))
```

I then construct a "list of alists".

```
(defun assoc-list ()
  "TODO"

  (let* ( (name "assoc-table-")
      (counter 1)
      (table '()) )

    (while (boundp (intern (concat name (number-to-string counter))))

      (setq table
         (append table
            (symbol-value (intern (concat name (number-to-string counter))))))
  (message "%s" (concat name (number-to-string counter)))
  (setq counter (1+ counter)))

table))
```

which I pass to this function

```
(defun shorten ()
  "Shorten word at point according to specific rules."
  (interactive)

  (let* ( (bounds  (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
      (word (downcase (buffer-substring (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
      (rplc "") )

    (goto-char (car bounds))
    (add-to-list 'nscrip word)

    (dolist (aggr (assoc-list))
       (setq rplc (cdr (assoc word aggr)))
       (unless (null rplc)
          (add-to-list 'nscrip
             (replace-regexp-in-string word rplc word))))
```

Thu function above fails on the first element because `assoc-list` consists of a `"list of alists"`, but `(assoc word aggr)` expects a list in `aggr`, but is getting an element with a dot in it.

How can I solve the problem encountered by `(assoc word aggr)`.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the evaluated `BODY`; your `dolist` parentheses are not even closed. A minimal example would probably help.

Comment: I added the `(assoc word aggr)` part that generates the problem.

Comment: There's no question here, just a piece of code and an unclear discussion of how it fails. You don't explain what you're trying to do and you don't explain what the problem is in a comprehensible way.

Comment: @Hovlar What is word? If it's not defined as a variable you should use `(setq rplc (cdr (assoc 'word aggr)))` in your second line. Note the apostrophe before word. As Gilles says you should provide a complete example with all your variables and lists declared

Comment: Have provided a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `assoc-list` does not produce a list of alists, it merges the `assoc-list-*` alists into one big alist.  This is because you use `append` to mash the alists together.

Here is a version that does what you intend:

```
(defun assoc-list ()
  "TODO"

  (let* ( (name "assoc-table-")
      (counter 1)
      table)

    (while (boundp (intern (concat name (number-to-string counter))))

      (push
       (symbol-value (intern (concat name (number-to-string counter))))
       table)
  (message "%s" (concat name (number-to-string counter)))
  (setq counter (1+ counter)))

table))
```

In detail: set `table` to `nil` (the empty list).  Then `push` each constituent alist into `table`.

You should look at the docstrings of both `push` and `append` to appreciate the difference.

General remark: evaluating your code in the scratch buffer makes it easy to see what kind of object yr code is returning.  Experimentation of this kind is what makes lisp so much fun and you should be doing way more of that instead of asking here every time.

Comment: Right.  I can see now how it is producing a list of alists.  I do get  `((("graphology" . "Gol") ("phrenology" . "fnol")) (("frantic" . "fN") ("authentic" . "atN")))`.

Comment: +1 particularly for the closing remark, which I hope the OP will heed.